# Can't access an element in JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, getjson

No one really answered this question but how on earth can one use this JSON return data from a php/mysql direct using JavaScript?

Here is the return data once i used `JSON.parse` and saved it to the Javascript variable `obj`

```
[{"stuid":"10-00002","stuname":"Meratis, Velino","stucourse":"Arts","stustat":"0","stulyear":"4","stulog":"feb 16 2017"},{"stuid":"10-00003","stuname":"Melker, Alana","stucourse":"Wilderness","stustat":"1","stulyear":"5","stulog":"feb 16 2017"}]
```

I've tried the simple `obj.stuname` but it returns only an `undefined` i've tried many times to understand it but i can't seem to use this array at all.
Could anyone help on this?

I've also tried the `reObj = {"stu":obj};` style but then it only returns an [object Object]

so please someone elaborate on this?

Comment: how you get from php, share your ajax request code also ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`obj` is a json `array`, so you have to access an element using its `index`.

Also, you have to use `JSON.parse` in order to turn a `string` of `json` text to a Javascript object.

Try this:

```
var stuname=obj[0].stuname;
```

```js
var obj='[{"stuid":"10-00002","stuname":"Meratis, Velino","stucourse":"Arts","stustat":"0","stulyear":"4","stulog":"feb 16 2017"},{"stuid":"10-00003","stuname":"Melker, Alana","stucourse":"Wilderness","stustat":"1","stulyear":"5","stulog":"feb 16 2017"}]';
var objParsed=JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(objParsed[0].stuname);
```

If you want to iterate `array`, use `forEach` method.

```js
var obj='[{"stuid":"10-00002","stuname":"Meratis, Velino","stucourse":"Arts","stustat":"0","stulyear":"4","stulog":"feb 16 2017"},{"stuid":"10-00003","stuname":"Melker, Alana","stucourse":"Wilderness","stustat":"1","stulyear":"5","stulog":"feb 16 2017"}]';
var objParsed=JSON.parse(obj);
objParsed.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item.stuname);
});
```

Comment: in addition i am using JSON encode from a php and send it via Json to a Javascript but it just says undefined when the data retrieved was perfect

Comment: thanks dude this helped a lot. but how do you use it on a for loop?

Comment: You means when I have a JSON string ?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are getting this response from php via ajax.
   Be sure to use `dataType` as `json` to get json type response not string.
2. Otherwise you need to parse json data like this

   ```
   obj = JSON.parse(jsonStrFromPhp);
   ```

Then you can fetch data as obj.stuname or obj[0].stuname depends how you returned from php like this `{"stu":obj}` or like this `[{"stu":obj}]`

Comment: i got the second one. the `[{}]` from my php. i can't seem to directly parse it coz if i only parse it, it just returns a `[object Object],[object Object]` so i had to stringify it then parse it afterwards to get my response. but it turned out to solve my problems

Answer (score 0):

while i was having a migraine... of why my code was wrong it turned out that even though the `obj = JSON.parse(jsonStrFromPhp);` returned only an `[object Object],[object Object]` javascript can actually understand that shins and returned my variable... how confusing.